# Object fields null when object is sent via a post command to spring WebApp

Tags: java, spring, angular, angular5

I've made a method that sends a post request to my spring web application for creating a new user. The object that is being sent has 3 fields namely userName, emailaddress and password.

I've already verified that the values are present the moment the object gets sent to the server. Below is my code:

Method in my UserService:

```
  createUser(newUser: UserCreateDTO): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.post<Response>(this.authUrl + "/user/create", newUser);
}
```

I've tried changing `Response` to `any` or to `UserCreateDTO`, yet the result is Always the same. The object arrivés but the fields are all null.

Method in my User component:

```
  createUser():void{
    this.loading = true;
      this.userService.createUser(new UserCreateDTO(this.userForm.get('userName').value, 
                this.userForm.get('emailAddress').value, 
                this.userForm.get('password').value))
      .subscribe((response: Response) => { 
        if(response.ok)
          this.msgs.push({severity:'success', summary:'Success', detail: response.statusText});
        else
          this.msgs.push({severity:'error', summary:'Error', detail: response.statusText});
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }
```

The object that is being sent:

```
export class UserCreateDTO {
    userName: string;
    emailAddress: string;
    password: string;

    constructor(userName?: string, emailAddress?: string, password?: string){
        this.userName = userName;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

This is the endpoint that receives the object on the server-side:

```
@PostMapping("/create")
private ResponseEntity<String> createNewUser(UserCreateDTO newUser) {
    Status status = userService.createUser(newUser);
    return ResponseEntity.status(status.isSuccess() ?
            HttpStatus.CREATED : HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(status.getInfo());
}
```

Can anyone give me a few pointers? Is the problem in my angular code or in my spring code? Thank you.

EDIT:

Below is the request payload:

```
{userName: "1", emailAddress: "1", password: "1"}
emailAddress
:
"1"
password
:
"1"
userName
:
"1"
```

So yes i think it is being sent. But i get a 500 response back because of the nullpointer exception that is being caused by the empty fields.

Comment: If you check in the browser developer tools (F12) network tab, can you see the request that's being sent? Are the fields in the request?

Comment: Can you share your UserCreateDTO pojo code?

Comment: I also recommend the developer tools. One more thing, simulate a REST call, e.g. with YARC for chrome.

Comment: @user184994  see my edit. @Aris i've already shared this, its right under the line `the object being sent`

Comment: You need to add the `@RequestBody` annotation before `(UserCreateDTO newUser)` in your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you need to tell the method where to get `newUser` from. In this case, it is from the POST body, so add the `@RequestBody` annotation, like so:

```
@PostMapping("/create")
private ResponseEntity<String> createNewUser(@RequestBody UserCreateDTO newUser) {
    Status status = userService.createUser(newUser);
    return ResponseEntity.status(status.isSuccess() ?
            HttpStatus.CREATED : HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(status.getInfo());
}
```